# Is there a way to add legend next to a dygraph in R, not exactly on the plot?

Tags: r, dygraphs

I'vw plotted a dygraph using a `dygraph` function from a [dygraphs](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/) R package. I wonder is there a way to put legend next to the plot, not exactly on it like it is done by default...

Code to reproduce this dygraph is below:

```
library(archivist)
library(dplyr)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rstudio/dygraphs")
library(dygraphs)
seriesReactive <- loadFromGithubRepo( "db914a43536d4d3f00cf3df8bf236b4a", user= "MarcinKosinski", repo="Museum", value = TRUE)
dygraph(seriesReactive, main = "Dzienna proporcja kliknięć do odsłon dla danych struktur", ylab = "Proporcja") %>% 
    dyRangeSelector()
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, read `?dygraphs::dyLegend`. The description of `labelsDiv` argument says:

> Show data labels in an external div, rather than on the graph. This value should be a div element id.

This is easy to do in a [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) context of course, but not in [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio).

For instance, in Shiny `ui.R` file, I have added this line:

```
box(title = "Legend", textOutput("legendDivID"))
```

Which creates an HTML `<div>` tag with the ID `legendDivID`.
Then, in Shiny `server.R` file, I use the same ID in [dygraphs](/questions/tagged/dygraphs) params:

```
dygraph(...) %>% dyLegend(labelsDiv = "legendDivID")
```

And it works like a charm.

In your case, here is the result:

[image]

And the code (just create `app.R` script in RStudio and run it by calling `shiny::runApp()`):

```
## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(dygraphs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Page title"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("tab title", tabName = "tab", icon = icon("globe")))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "tab",
              fluidRow(
                  box(dygraphOutput("graph"), width=9),
                  box(textOutput("legendDivID"), title = "Legend", collapsible = TRUE, width=3)
                )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  library(archivist)
  library(dplyr)
  seriesReactive <- loadFromGithubRepo( "db914a43536d4d3f00cf3df8bf236b4a", user= "MarcinKosinski", repo="Museum", value = TRUE)

  output$graph <- renderDygraph({
    withProgress(message = "Loading...", {
      dygraph(seriesReactive, main = "Dzienna proporcja kliknięć do odsłon dla danych struktur", ylab = "Proporcja") %>% 
        dyRangeSelector() %>%
        dyLegend(labelsDiv = "legendDivID")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I've seen it. What does it mean? Do I need to specify any .css file? Do I have to know javascript, css or html? I only know R language. More over do you think there are any sample div fot that case?

Comment: div is an html tag (<div>) used to define a section. This is why Shiny is involved and not base R. Let me try to produce an example then I'll give you a feedback