# dygraphs legend outside plot in shiny app for multiple plots

Tags: r, shiny, dygraphs

I have this shiny app where I'm plotting several `dygraphs`. Unfortunately, I dont't know how many plots there will be plottet. It may vary from time to time. So I came up with using `uiOutput` and `renderUI` to build an app that reacts on the number of plots. See https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Now I wnat to show the legend of each `dygraph` outside the respective plot as was shown here: [Is there a way to add legend next to a dygraph in R, not exactly on the plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653816/is-there-a-way-to-add-legend-next-to-a-dygraph-in-r-not-exactly-on-the-plot)

My problem is now that the `<div>` elements of the legend do not have the same height as the ones of the plots.

My code is:

UI:

```
library(dygraphs)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Simple example"),
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
   fluidRow(column(10, uiOutput("graphs")),
            column(2, uiOutput("legends")))
   )
 )
))
```

server:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

# load xts sample data
data("sample_matrix")
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

output$graphs <- renderUI({ 
 plot_output_list <- lapply(1:3, function(i) { 
  dygraphOutput(paste0('div_graph_', i)) 
 }) 
})

output$legends <- renderUI({
 legend_output_list <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {
   htmlOutput(paste0("div_legende",i), height = "400px")
 })
})

# do the plotting
lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  output[[paste0('div_graph_', i)]] <- renderDygraph({
   dygraph(sample.xts[,i],main=i)%>%
    dyLegend(labelsDiv = paste0("div_legende",i), show = "always")
  })
 })
})
```

This leads to this plot, where you can see the legends of all three plots are directly pasted together. I want them to be right of their respective plot.

[image: sample plot with legend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
Creating a `plotOutput` and an empty `plot` does the trick:

Ui stays the same.
Server:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(xts)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

 data("sample_matrix")
 sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)

 output$graphs <- renderUI({ 
  plot_output_list <- lapply(1:3, function(i) { 
  dygraphOutput(paste0('div_graph_', i)) 
 }) 
})

output$legends <- renderUI({
 legend_output_list <- lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  plotOutput(paste0("div_legende",i), height = "400px")
 })
})

lapply(1:3, function(i) {
  output[[paste("div_legende",i)]] <- renderPlot(
    plot(1,1,type="n",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",ylab="",xlab="",bty="n"),
    height = "400px"
  )
  output[[paste0('div_graph_', i)]] <- renderDygraph({
  dygraph(sample.xts[,i],main=i)%>%
    dyLegend(labelsDiv = paste0("div_legende",i),
             show = "always")
  })
 })
})
```