# Change the position of legend in dygraph in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

How can I change the position of the legend in `dygraphs` in R?

The legend always appears in the right top and I would like to move it outside the graph.

Comment: Potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653816/is-there-a-way-to-add-legend-next-to-a-dygraph-in-r-not-exactly-on-the-plot

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how to put legend outside the plot, hovewer, by changing width parameter in legend could move your legend from up-right to up-left.

For example, this part of code puts my legend to up-right corner of my plot:

"your part of code above" %>%
dyLegend(show = "always", width = 130)

Maybe this partially helps)